# Identify errors between two worksheets

Tags: excel-2010

I have two sheets in same workbook. Sheet1 is having the data to be updated and sheet2 is having the data after the update. I want to highlight the errors in Sheet2, with comments beside the cell "E" as  *Wrong Date Entered*. I have tried using VLOOKUP formula but it did not work.

[image: Sheet 1(Data to be Updated)]
[image: Sheet 2 (Data after the Update)]

Formula Used: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3,ti,5,FALSE),"Wrong Date Entered")

Comment: Identify is a broad term. Do you want to highlight the differences? Delete the errors? Move the errors to a third worksheet? Attempt correction? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the date from Sheet1 with a multiple field criteria (using `IFERROR` to retrieve the new entries) and compare the dates.

[image: Identify errors in updates]

The formula in SHeet2!F2 is,

```
=IF(E2=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$9,MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$8)+((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9<>A2)+(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9<>B2)+(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9<>C2)+(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$9<>D2))*1E+99,,))), E2),"", "Wrong Date Entered")
```

Fill down as necessary. When transcribing for your own purposes, remember that `ROW(1:8)` is the *position within* Sheet1!E2:E9, not the actual row on the worksheet.
**EDIT:**

I opened up the Sheet1 ranges to look at 9999 rows then filtered for the error message and came up with the following.

[image: Updated identify errors in updates]

The formula with the larger cell ranges I used was,

```
=IF(E2=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$9999,MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$9998)+((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9999<>A2)+(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9999<>B2)+(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9999<>C2)+(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$9999<>D2))*1E+99,,))), E2),"", "Wrong Date Entered")
```

When filling the formula down it did take a few seconds to calculate but I'm only using an older business class laptop so I don't think that the calculation lag was anything completely out of the acceptable range.

Comment: how can i use this formula for dynamic range or how can i apply this formula for entire worksheet. I have tried changing range but I m not able to get the output.

Comment: @user3032425 - *entire worksheet* is another broad term that could have many meanings. For a dynamic range, you could use a *named range* where the `Refers to:` is determined by a formula using `INDEX` or `OFFSET`. Sheet2 only needs to have the formula in column F filled down. If the cell range references to Sheet1 need expanding, this could be done with editing the formula. Consider uploading a redacted copy of your workbook with Sheet1 and Sheet2 to a public file area and posting a link to the file back here.

Comment: Here is the link.[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/qiz9xdjki4crw89/Book1.xlsx?dl=0[/link]

Comment: Sheet 2 data can be more than Sheet 1 and vice versa.

Comment: @user3032425 - Please see the modifications added to my response above.

Answer (score 0):

You can save both files as pdfs and can compare those files using Acrobat Pro.
Goto **View -> Compare Documents..**

Comment: With all of the functionality within Excel 2010 (VBA, formulas, conditional formatting, filtering, etc) why would you recommend a solution involving another commercial application that the OP may not even have access to?